# How Can i read the preview frames from the actual opensource android Camera

Tags: android

How can i read the preview frames from the actual camera source code? I am trying to modify the actual source code of camera application in android for reading the preview frames. Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to change the actual source code for reading frames.  Implementing the [Camera.PreviewCallback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html) interface should suffice.  It returns raw data from the camera.

Comment: Thanx alot your reply, i tried adding the previewcallback but it is returning only one frames, i need all the frames in the preview.

Comment: It returns a frame every time one is read.  You're getting all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Before messing with the source of the camera app try the example here:
[CameraPreview](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html)
Then implement the Camera.PreviewCallback. 
The captured frame comes in YUV420SP so you have to convert it to rgb in order to convert it into a colored bitmap and show it on screen.
Like this :

```
        @Override
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        int imageWidth = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width  ;
        int imageHeight =camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height ;
        int RGBData[] = new int[imageWidth* imageHeight]; 
        byte[] mYUVData = new byte[data.length];    
        System.arraycopy(data, 0, mYUVData, 0, data.length);
        decodeYUV420SP(RGBData, mYUVData, imageWidth, imageHeight);

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageWidth, imageHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bitmap.setPixels(RGBData, 0, imageWidth, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
    }

    static public void decodeYUV420SP(int[] rgb, byte[] yuv420sp, int width, int height) {
            final int frameSize = width * height;

            for (int j = 0, yp = 0; j < height; j++) {
            int uvp = frameSize + (j >> 1) * width, u = 0, v = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++, yp++) {
                int y = (0xff & ((int) yuv420sp[yp])) - 16;
                if (y < 0) y = 0;
                if ((i & 1) == 0) {
                    v = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
                    u = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
                }

                int y1192 = 1192 * y;
                int r = (y1192 + 1634 * v);
                int g = (y1192 - 833 * v - 400 * u);
                int b = (y1192 + 2066 * u);

                if (r < 0) r = 0; else if (r > 262143) r = 262143;
                if (g < 0) g = 0; else if (g > 262143) g = 262143;
                if (b < 0) b = 0; else if (b > 262143) b = 262143;

                rgb[yp] = 0xff000000 | ((r << 6) & 0xff0000) | ((g >> 2) & 0xff00) | ((b >> 10) & 0xff);
            }
        }
    }
```